# Identify and replace minimum value from a numeric column present in all dataframes in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I need a way to identify the minimum value in a particular column presents in all dataframes in a list of dataframes and replace it with some non-numeric character. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=c(2,4,6))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=c(10,20,30))
myList <- list(df1, df2)


[[1]]
  x y
1 a 2
2 b 4
3 c 6

[[2]]
  x  y
1 a 10
2 b 20
3 c 30
```

should become

```
[[1]]
  x y
1 a *
2 b 4
3 c 6

[[2]]
  x  y
1 a *
2 b 20
3 c 30
```

What's the best way? It would be great if someone knew a Base R and external packages (purrr) solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```
lapply(myList, function(df) transform(df, y = replace(y, which.min(y), "*")))
#[[1]]
#  x y
#1 a *
#2 b 4
#3 c 6
#
#[[2]]
#  x  y
#1 a  *
#2 b 20
#3 c 30
```

Or the same in the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(myList, ~.x %>% mutate(y = replace(y, which.min(y), "*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      for(i in 1:length(myList)){
  currMin = min(myList[[i]]$y)
  myList[[i]]$y[myList[[i]]$y==currMin] <- '*'
}
```

please note, assigning '*' will convert type to character